# Basic C# Mime Decoding

Tags: c#, .net, mime

Is there a clean way of handling multi-part MIME data in C#.

After a call to a closed application (I have no access to change it) I get a MIME reponse like the one below.  Does C# provide the ability to parse this via System.Net.Mime or System.Net.Mail?

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; 
    boundary="----=_Part_42_31322961.1286389502467"

------=_Part_42_31322961.1286389502467
Content-Type: text/xml
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-ID: <xmlContextInfo>
<UnneededXML> <Stuff> </Stuff> </UnneededXML>


------=_Part_42_31322961.1286389502467
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-ID: <myImage>

/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAgGBgcGBQgHBwcJCQgKDBQNDAsLDBkSEw8UHRofHh0a
```

All I really need from the response is the "myImage" portion (which is much longer than what is shown above)

Comment: were you able to parse your stuff yet? did any of the below answers help?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [OpenPOP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hpop/) library which includes mime parser.

Answer (score 2):

[MimeKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit) works well 
I had been previously using code from [Codeplex POP3 MIME Support](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15611/POP-Email-Client-with-full-MIME-Support-NET) but it has failed to parse some mimeContent and had to look for alternatives.

Comment: MimeKit is awesome even in the year 2021!

Answer (score 1):

There's also this one:
http://anmar.eu.org/projects/sharpmimetools/