# C# extract HTML from MHT file

Tags: c#, html, mhtml

I have a C# module that extracts information from a HTML file. But my input is a MHT file. How do I go about extracting just the html portion of the MHT file?

Comment: MHTML files are _Mime HTML_ files. You need a Mime parser/decoder. [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3876406/basic-c-sharp-mime-decoding)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried several tools & libraries that reportedly allowed me to extract the contents of a MHT, but almost all failed (I found that the provider of the MHT files did not encode some types correctly). I eventually discovered Total Commander which let me unpack the MHT and extract just the html portion. It was a hack, but it got the job done.

It would seem that there are many tools for creating MHTs and few for unpacking them.