# Flurl AddFile fileName Encoding

Tags: c#, utf-8, flurl

I try to use `flurl` to send a file like this:

```
public ImportResponse Import(ImportRequest request, string fileName, Stream stream)
    {
        request).PostAsync(content).Result<ImportTariffResponse>();

        return FlurlClient(Routes.Import, request).PostMultipartAsync(mp => mp.AddJson("json", request).AddFile("file", stream, ConvertToAcsii(fileName))).Result<ImportResponse>();
    }
```

fileName = "Файл импорта тарифов (1).xlsx"

But in post method I get this:

> Request.Files.FirstOrDefault().FileName =
>   "=?utf-8?B?0KTQsNC50Lsg0LjQvNC/0L7RgNGC0LAg0YLQsNGA0LjRhNC+0LIgKDEpLnhsc3g=?="

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please post the definition of the ConvertToAcsii method.

Comment: Sorry to confuse, his empty: private string ConvertToAcsii(string str)
        {
            return str;
        }

Comment: I have standart C# utf8 string at the entrance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filename appears to be encoded using [MIME encoded-word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Encoded-Word) syntax. (Flurl doesn't do this directly, it presumably happens deeper down in the HttpClient libraries when non-ASCII characters are detected.) [.NET doesn't directly support decoding this format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10828807/decode-a-utf-8b-string-in-c-sharp), but you can do it yourself fairly easily. If you strip the `=?utf-8?B?` from the beginning and `?=` from the end, what you're left with is your filename base64 encoded.

Here's one way you could do it:

```
var base64 = Request.Files.FirstOrDefault().FileName.Split('?')[3];
var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
var filename = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```